# Enabling command logging on a Cisco MDS Switch

Tags: cisco, logging, switch, tacacs+

We are able to send all commands entered by admins to syslog on our Pix and ASA devices but are having trouble finding the correct commands or log levels to do the same for our Cisco MDS 9xxx switches.

Is it a matter of enabling the correct log levels (for example, we cannot set terminal log level above 3 (Critical) due to terminal Baud Rate issues), or is it a matter of somehow explicitly enabling command logging?

At the moment we successfully get "Configuration Updated" messages in Syslog, but we want to see what the actual commands were (i.e. what configuration changes were made).

The normal switch commands do not seem to work on MDS series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the MDS runs SAN-OS and not IOS as most other devices.  It does not appear to be able to syslog the actual changes that were made.  However, it does support AAA accounting to a TACACS server to log this information, that may be what you need to do.